# What's the name of this dice set with blue letters on red-and-black?

Tags: dice, product-identification

I have a red speckled dice set with blue numbers, and I think the company that made them was Chessex. However, I have searched Google for a few minutes, but could find nothing on this set. I also have the Chessex Speckled Cobalt and Chessex Speckled Recon, which is my information on these dice. The dice themselves look like the Speckled Silver Volcano, but the numbers are the same color as the Cobalt or the Blue Stars. So that rules the Strawberry and the Volcano speckled dice out. Thanks for your help.

I have taken a picture, these are the dice I don't know the name of:

[image: red and black speckled dice]
<sup>(Click for larger version.)</sup>

My only camera is pretty poor quality, so the picture below might help. These aren't the exact same, but very similar style, just different number color:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was a set named [Veronica Speckled, by Chessex](http://www.chessex.com/Dice/Speckled%20pages/25324.htm). I was searching for it as well but looks like they no longer make it.

Per e-mail with Chessex on 2018/02/08:

> Veronica is an out of print color and we do not have any of the 7-die sets available. The only set still available is the 10 d10 set. We do have some of the loose dice shapes as well. It looks like we have d4, d6 and d8.
>
> Unfortunately, some of our old webpage spaces are still searchable. Hopefully one day we will be able to properly update our website to fix that problem.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: [Veronica Speckled™ appears to still be for sale on Chessex's site.](http://www.chessex.com/Dice/Speckled%20pages/25324.htm) Nice ID!

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't appear to be *linked* from anywhere on the site... I can't seem to navigate to it, but Googling "Veronica Speckled dice" takes me right to it. Perhaps it is no longer available? I'm going to drop them an e-mail and see what they say.

Comment: Yep, I saw the old webpage and that's the dice I have that has blue numbers and the red speckles. It's also slightly blue speckled, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 5):

I believe I have the set you are describing. I definitely have the set in the second image. Part of the reason for the difficulty in identifying them is that the number colour for this set has changed during its run. I believe, but cannot confirm that the specific name of the set has also changed from time to time.

The company responsible is Chessex, and when introduced the line was called Mercury. These were described as black and red speckled dice. They have had silver, white, and gold numbering to my knowledge since introduction.

The 'mercury' pattern with silver numbers is now known as 'Silver Volcano', I believe. A search for mercury will reveal its current coloration (yellow/gold) numbers.

Comment: The number color on the dice is actually blue, the top photo is the dice, the second is just for easier pattern recognition. It is not silver, white or gold in person, I know that because I have the (currently) unidentified set and they are actually blue in person.

Comment: I can confirm that Chessex changes colors over the years and recycles names. I have two sets of Golden Cobalt that are remarkably different - one is more of a white gold, and the other is more brassy, but they're both "Golden Cobalt".

Comment: I'm not denying that it is a "Mercury" set, it's just not any of the ones Runeslinger described as they have colors that I do not have on the numbers of my dice.